# Can not get innerHTML to work?

Tags: javascript, html

Why does my code not work? Shouldn't it print `222` to the element with ID `p2`?

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="java.io.*" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
function compareData()
{
document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = "111";
var inputs = document.getElemementsByTagName("input");
// why can't I display the "222" here??
document.getElementById('p2').innerHTML = "222";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="p1"> a </p>

<p id="p2"> b </p>
<input type="button" onclick="compareData()" value="hello"/> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Why you are using this? `var inputs = document.getElemementsByTagName("input");`

[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rYH54/)

And you can use the way you are using like this : [**My fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rYH54/1/) but it was not working because Elements spelling is wrong **document.getElemementsByTagName**

It should be `document.getElementsByTagName`

Answer (score 3):

You have mis-spelled `getElemementsByTagName`. This results in a js error, thereby your code stops execution at that line.
Correct it as `getElementsByTagName`. Then your code would work fine.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo on this line:

```
var inputs = document.getElemementsByTagName("input");
```

What you want is probably this:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

It could be that the typo stops the execution of the script, and therefor the line after is never run.

Answer (score 2):

Remove following line and it will work...

```
var inputs = document.getElemementsByTagName("input");
```